# Too much Rosemary

Tags: flavor, soup, herbs, mistakes

I put too much Rosemary spice in a pureed vegetable soup.  Ingredients were onions, peppers, celery, ,cauliflower, vegetable broth, tamari and Rosemary and coconut milk. The Rosemary is too strong. How can I save it?

Comment: The problem is it's a pureed soup -- if you had caught this before, I'd have considered draining the liquid and freezing it in small amounts to use similar @user110084 suggested, but more as a flavor enhancement for soups or sauces.  (and then either serve the vegetables as a side, or add some corrected broth to it to make it back to a soup).  It's also worth mentioning that rosemary is one of the few herbs that you don't assume 1tsp dried is equiv to 1TB fresh -- it's closer to 1:1.

Comment: And depending on the consistency ... you might try tweaking it to be a sauce over pasta or rice ... or cook some potato and blend it with some of the soup and maybe some olive oil to make some flavorful mashed potatoes.  (if you bake them, it'll absorb more liquid)

Comment: Is the problem bitterness (salt and sugar can sometimes mask it) or too strong aroma?

Comment: My condolences. You can try adding strong pungent flavors that work well with rosemary like pecorino Romano, but it would probably still be pretty unpleasant to eat.

Answer (score 5):

Make a second soup with out rosemary and combine the two final products.

Or call it Rosemary Soup.

Answer (score 2):

I was inspired by @StevenXavier's answer.

Instead of remaking the soup, however, consider doubling the broth and coconut milk, then adding equal parts dried sage, thyme, marjoram, and celery salt* to make it akin to a poultry seasoning. It might end up tasting a bit like stuffing/dressing, but could be salvageable. Salt and pepper to taste, of course.

*and maybe a bit of nutmeg, opinions on poultry seasoning vary.